# How to create a command that inserts an image as frame for its content?

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros, graphics

I am writing an RPG book for Vampire and my intention is to add a command to create, based on input parameters, the character sheet of some NPCs that will be on my book.

I tested some fixes for the behaviour but got no positive result.

```
\newcommand{\MortalCSheet}[1]{
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \includegraphics[scale=0.7]{art/page/3Ed/charsheet-transp}
    \end{tikzpicture}   
    \begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|}
        Strength & Charisma & Perception \\
    \end{tabular}
}
```

The result I get is as the picture shows.[image]

My intention is to place the image and content (Strength & Charisma & Perception) within the image and it is printed on the spot the command is inserted. How can I get that result?

Comment: If you put \includegraphics in a node and the tabular in another node, all you have to do is use the same coordinates (center).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`callouts`](https://ctan.org/pkg/callouts?lang=en) and `tikz` packages. The first allows you to annotate a graphics and tikz allows you to draw anything on the image you are annotating. So, all you have to do is find where you wanna put it i.e. `{3, 2.75}` and the content `{text}`.

Edit: added command definition and argument handling.

I used the a command with `[2]` arguments. using `1` gets you the value of the first.

When you want to instantiate a card, you would call the command with the correct arguments. You can add more arguments `[3]` or more.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{callouts}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand{\MortalCSheet}[2]{%
\begin{annotate}
    {\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{#1}}{1}
    \helpgrid[gray] % <----- this is a helper grid
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \draw [thick, purple] (-6 ,-3) rectangle (-3,-4);
    \draw [thick, purple] (-2,-3)  rectangle (1,-4);
    \draw [thick, purple] (2 ,-3)  rectangle (5,-4);

    \node at (-4.5,-3.5) {Strength};
    \node at (-.5,-3.5) {Chrisma};
    \node at (3.5,-3.5) {Perception};
    
    \node at (0,3){#2};
\end{annotate}%
}

\begin{document}        
    \MortalCSheet{example-image-a}{name of this card}
\end{document}
```

Comment: But this does not solve the problem because I still have a mispositioned graphics and now some texts outside

Comment: Result here: https://ibb.co/NCSjCzt

Command redefined as suggested to
\newcommand{\NewMortalCSheet}[1]{
 \includegraphics[scale=0.7]{art/page/3Ed/charsheet-transp};S
 \helpgrid[gray]; % <----- this is a helper grid
 \draw [thick, purple] (1.65 ,1) rectangle (5, 2.25);
 \note {3, 2.75}{some text here};
}

Comment: let me add the command

Comment: Almost there. The only issue that seems to be the problem here is why it overlaps other columns of the text and the nodes cross the borders as we can see on Strength, Charisma and Perception.

https://ibb.co/6gXLLK4